# Retrieving notes of a Facebook page with an app access token

Tags: facebook-opengraph, facebook-fql, access-token

I have an app which retrieves events and photos from a facebook page and shows them on a website. Both the facebook page and the website belong to the same company, i.e. they're using their facebook page to manage events and photos they show on their website.

Now the client would like the same arrangement for notes: Use the public notes on their facebook page as blog entries on their website. I'm grabbing the photos and events via the PHP SDK with an app access token, but when I try to get the pages' notes I get an error "A user access token is required to request this resource."

Is there any way to access the public notes of a page with an app access token or, alternatively, is there an appropriate fql query to get all the public notes of a particular facebook page?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at [note](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/notes/) and [page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/) tables, for instance I can get all the public notes posted by facebook.com/amazon using the query below -

```
SELECT uid, note_id, title, content, created_time, updated_time FROM note WHERE uid in (select page_id from page where username = 'amazon')
```